# How to plot a histogram with different colors in R

Tags: r, visualization, data-visualization

I have a dataset of about 500 integer values in a csv file, with each value between 50-89. I am trying to create a histogram in R in which the bars that represent values 50-65 are bronze colored, 66-74 silver, and 75-89 gold. The script I have so far is the following:

```
dat1 <- read.csv("test2.csv", header=F)$V1
hist(dat1, main="Distribution of Player Ratings", xlim = c(0,99), breaks=c(seq(40,99,5)))
```

A sample of test2.csv is shown below (extremely simple)

```
69,
68,
67,
65,
65,
62,
59,
59,
54,
```

Right now my graph is:

[image: My Graph]

What would I have to do in order to fulfill the color guidelines explained earlier?

*Note:* I had posted this question earlier, but without any of my code or a reference to my dataset.

Comment: You can go through [r-cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the `col` arguments in the `hist` method as follows:

```
t<- c(69,68,67,65,65,62,59,59,54)
hist(t, main="Distribution of Player Ratings",xlim = c(0,99), 
       breaks=c(seq(40,99,5)), col = c("blue", "red", "gray", "green"))
```

See the image I got after above execution:

[image]

Now you can replace the colour values(either name or hexadecimal values like "#FFFF00") as per your requirements.

Answer (score 6):

In your earlier question, you had mentioned `ggplot2`, so here is a `ggplot2` solution:

First simulate your dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(X = sample(50:89, 500, replace = T))
```

Add a new variable that defines your color criteria:

```
df$group = ifelse(df$X < 66, "50-65", ifelse(df$X < 75, "66-74", "75-89"))
```

Now, load the `ggplot2` library to create a histogram

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(X, fill = group)) + geom_histogram()
```

To give custom colors, use `scale_fill_manual`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(X, fill = group)) + geom_histogram() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("50-65" = "#CD7F32",
                                 "66-74" = "#C0C0C0",
                                 "75-89" = "gold"))
```

This is how the figure looks like now:

[image]

Although you included `xlim = c(0,99)` (which is not visible in the attached plot), I don't know why you would use that. If you wish you can add an `xlim` argument with `+ xlim(0,99)`.

To learn more about `ggplot2`, look [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/).

**Note:** You can define the number of bins or binwidth in `geom_histogram`. Refer [this](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_histogram.html) for more