# R colour percentage bin histogram

Tags: r, colors, histogram, percentage

how can I get an histogram in R such that the colour of each bin corresponds to the percentage of ok/valid/true cases of the total? I mean, the histogram shows the number of cases per bin, so I get the distribution over all the x-range. However, I would like also to fill each bin with a colour showing which was the percentage of any condition (satisfactory, true...) in each interval...

Any help is welcome! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use histogram use
hist(df$colname)
Also check these two links provided below

https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-make-a-histogram-with-ggplot2/

[How to plot a histogram with different colors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810453/how-to-plot-a-histogram-with-different-colors-in-r)

Comment: Very helpful reply! Unfortunately, my problem is how to set the percentage argument. It is ok to set the colour by count, and also by a conditional count, but how to set the percentage?